# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.ObjectCompareObjectEqual

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I had a code segment on an asp.net page in the code-behind file. I decided to move it into a public subroutine in a module (general_functions.vb). Once I did this, however, the code no longer works - it throws an error.

On the original code-behind I replaced the original code with a call like so:

```
DeleteResidency(people_id, semester, year)
```

Now in my general_functions.vb I created a public subroutine like follows:

```
Public Sub DeleteResidency(delpeople_id, delsemester, delyear)
    Using dbContext as pbu_housingEntities = New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim remove_selection = (From p in dbContext.Residents _
                               Where p.people_code_id = delpeople_id _
                               Where p.year = delyear _
                               Where p.semester = delsemester _
                               Order By p.id Descending _
                               Select p).FirstOrDefault
    End Using
End Sub
```

There is more code to it than that, but the code above is what throws the error. The error I get is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
>   CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can anyone help me understand why this is occurring?

Comment: What is the type of `semester`?

Comment: All values are cast as strings.

Comment: I suspect there is some non primitive type comparison in your where conditions.

Comment: And this is why I always explicitly type my parameters.

Comment: NoAlias - thanks, I just explicitly typed them all as string and now the code works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Explicitly type your parameters in the definition of the DeleteResidency Sub Routine.  This leaves less for the compiler to infer and prevents these types of errors.